# Cómo reenvío tokens en los headers para todos las peticiones usando angularjs y satelizer

Tags: angularjs, nodejs

Estoy usando tokens para almacenar las sesiones de un usuario.

Ya hice el servidor en nodejs, ahora la cuestión es como hacer el cliente en angular.

Mis rutas son:

```
localhost:3000/user/auth (get && post)
localhost:3000/user/login (get && post)
```

Este es mi controlador en angular para el login, estoy usando [satellizer](https://github.com/sahat/satellizer)

```
function LoginController($auth,$state,$scope,$window) {  

    $scope.login = function(){
        $auth.login({
            email: $scope.email,
            password: $scope.password
        })
        .then(function(req){

          console.log(req);
          $auth.setToken(req.data.token);
          $auth.getToken();
          //$window.location.href="/secret";
        })
        .catch(function(req){
            console.log(req);
        });
    }
    $scope.authenticate=function(provider){
      $auth.authenticate(provider);
    }

}
```

Una vez que el usuario se logea, como hago para que en todas las peticiones el cliente envíe el token y pueda acceder a sitios restringidos?

En la parte que les puse, logro capturar el token y almacenarlo en el storage de satellizer, pero no se como hacer la réplica.

Comment: Si estás usando satelizer no tienes que hacer nada, ni siquiera usar un interceptor ya que satelizer tiene uno activo por defecto. Lee la [doc](https://github.com/sahat/satellizer#question-how-can-i-avoid-sending-authorization-header-on-all-http-requests). Comprobaste que el token se estuviera mandando en cada request?

Comment: hola , si a comprobe que el token se envie , ya use     $authProvider.authHeader  y $authProvider.authHeader
pero solo funciona en el ambito del app estoy usando ui.router para cargar algunas vistas , pero la vista secreta lo redirecciono con <a>, pero en la vista secreta no se envia el token ,
 localhost:3000/secret

Comment: Si estás abriendo otra página usando un `<a>` el servicio `$http` nunca entra en efecto pues no lo estás usando y por lo tanto el interceptor de satellizer tampoco funciona. Si quieres que se envíe el token debes usar `$http.get` pero con el contenido actual de tu pregunta es difícil entender que estás tratando de lograr.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En teoria necesitas al momento de una autenticacion exitosa guardar el token en algun lado (un servicio angular dedicado a guardar data del usuario) y algun encargado de interceptar todas las peticiones http tomar el token de tu servicio y agregarlo a las peticiones, para eso en angular existen los [http interceptors](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#interceptors) si tienes dominio basico de como manejar los servicios en angular deberias poder unir los dos conceptos y hacerlo. Si tiene problema dime y puedo ayudarte con algo de codigo

Comment: lo probaré gracias.

Answer (score 0):

yo te recomiendo poner los datos de logeo en nodejs gracias al modulo express-session o cookie-session, y en cada ruta que sea privada solo para los que se logeen en el servidor entonces poner una condicional de que si se ha logeado entonces acceder a tal ruta de la pagina.

Es muy facil de usar y te evita tener que escribir codigo en el lado del navegador porque el nodejs ya le envia esos datos al navegador y cuando haces alguna peticion al servidor, el navegador se lo envia por si mismo no lo tienes que hacer tu.

investiga el modulo cookie-session o express-session cualquiera de los dos te funcionara.

Comment: lo probaré , muchas gracias.

Comment: aqui  te paso un link de youtube del canal codigo facilito donde te explican como usar el modulo        https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mFfsmKO2LiI&list=PLxQpvaAx698Ay5e1JxlORXzH30JB9GbMs&index=31

Answer (score 0):

Con el uso de Interceptors en AngularJS, puedes interceptar cada llamada al servidor y agregarle el token en el HEADER de cada llamada.

LINKS: 1) https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

2) http://www.webdeveasy.com/interceptors-in-angularjs-and-useful-examples/